# Fix large bad-formatted xml files

Tags: xml

Is there any library for fixing large (>200MB) bad-formatted (missing closed tags, unmatched quotes, non-escaped characters, non-printable characters, etc.) xml files? A library in any programming language is okay. I found [PHP Tidy](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) that works for small files only since it read the whole file into memory.

Comment: What is a "bad formatted XML file"? Is the XML wrong? Or is it just messy looking when you try and read it in a browser?

Comment: What size - large is not that useful a measure - also how are they broken as tidy only fixes HTML

Comment: There is no way in general to fix XML - is the file meant to be HTML?

Comment: The way to fix XML is to have the creators of the XML not send broken XML.

Comment: @John - I don't think they will listen to me. Too big a name.

Comment: You can tell anybody "no" if you're correct. Simply remind them that you can't read minds so you don't know what was intended when the garbage was created. You could also appeal to XMLSpy, which is also a big name. If XMLspy can't read it, then it's not XML.

Comment: In general, there's no way to know _where_ to place closing tags, etc. The person who created the "XML" knows what they intended the data to mean - that's who needs to learn how to create XML that matches the semantics they intended.

Answer (score 2):

Tidy can do that, with the `-asxhtml` or `-asxml` flags:

```
tidy -asxhtml input.xml output.xml
```

It has also an impressive functionality for the indentation of the output (by default it does not generate a very beautiful one).

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has HTMLTidy included; it can be configured to fix XML, though you should be prepared to have your elements values either truncated/removed/or repositioned; thus breaking the semantic layout of the XML document itself.

In any case, it is usefull to use Notepad++ to manually fix the XML anyway, as you can use the collapse/expand tool and indent to track XML nodes that are working properly, and work through the file until the fixing is complete.

If you have an XML schema for your file, you could repair the file and then validate it against that schema to find nodes that were moved about, if there are few you might be able to fix them manually.

In any case, there is no fix/repair tool that I know of that will do this for you without significant manual effort.

Comment: But PHP Tidy the OP uses uses HTML Tidy so there will be the same memory issue.

Comment: @simbolo - And I'm looking for a programmatic way.

Comment: @Ethan, there is no programmatic way to do what you're asking. You fix them manually or not at all if you want your XML to remain intact. ANY programatic method will truncate/remove/reposition your XML tree, which will make it just as useless.

Comment: @Mark As for the memory issue, I think that if Ethan got results he liked using PHP Tidy etc on smaller files, then he should seek a machine with sufficient resources to parse a 200MB XML file in memory, so long as the process is functioning, I'd leave it running on my work machine for the weekend and see if it made any progress.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tidy to the rescue:

```
tidy -xml input.file output.file
```

Just understand tidy can't do miracles, just try to reconstruct into a valid XML file. Consider you probably are losing data.

http://www.html-tidy.org/

Comment: It does not work, it would enforce a well-formed xml of the input file and stop with error if it is not. The goal is to fix the input file, and not to show that it is badly formatted.

Comment: Tidy has been rewritted at least once. Maybe they changed the behavior.